# Acronis Disk Image cannot clone to the same storage SSD

Tags: ssd

I wanted to clone my computer.
My computer is using 450gb SSD.

I used Acronis disk image to clone the SDD to another new SSD (with same storage 450gb) but the new SSD cannot show in Acronis disk image software. (New SSD has already formatted)

I tried to use bigger storage HDD that is 1tb. This time, it successfully clone.
Why it cannot clone to the same storage SSD?

Comment: https://www.acronis.com/en-us/support/

Comment: The title of your question is misleading. It sounds as if you want to make a image operation where the target is the source.